# Hosting a SilverLight website

Tags: c#, silverlight-2.0

I am new to web development and am seeking some help :-)

I have followed a silver light tutorial to build a basic silverlight app.

http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/pages/silverlight-2-end-to-end-tutorial-building-a-digg-search-client.aspx

i then hosted this app on aspspider. 
i have now modified the app to connect to a SQLExpress Db. this uses a 'WCF service' and 'Linq to sql classes' to perform the db search. This all works perfectly in Visualstudio however i am not sure how to make it work in the aspSpider host.

So far i have managed to attach the Db, and get the silver light xap to work. but obviously when i click the search button in the website i get a blank screen as the service fails.

Any help would be fantastic !!!

Bellow is a list of the files in the project.

Comment: More details needed but...
Make sure you can connect to the database. I would do this by makeing a small silverlight app that does nothing but connects to the database or prints out a nice error message if it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is due to cross-domain policy of silverlight. Refer to the following link
http://blogs.msdn.com/silverlightws/archive/2008/03/30/some-tips-on-cross-domain-calls.aspx